# Parsing PDML / XML and selecting specific fields for Pandas

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am using the ElementTreeXML API and trying to parse a large PDML (XML) file in Python. I am trying to get a tabular Pandas dataframe output with specific fields of information. The following is a subset of the actual file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="pdml2html.xsl"?>
<!-- You can find pdml2html.xsl in C:\Program Files\Wireshark or at https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=pdml2html.xsl. -->
<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/3.2.2" time="Sun Mar 22 23:53:43 2020" capture_file="C:\Users\anyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\wireshark_Wi-Fi 2_20200322234518_a20824.pcapng">
<packet>
  <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="66">
    <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="66"/>
    <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="66"/>
    <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
    <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="66" showname="Captured Length" value="42" size="66"/>
    <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Mar 22, 2020 23:45:34.045301000 Pacific Daylight Time" showname="Captured Time" value="1584945934.045301000" size="66"/>
  </proto>
```

I want to get a table like:

```
field            size    value
frame.cap_len    0       null
frame.marked     0       null
timestamp        66      1584945934.045301000
```

I am really struggling with the syntax to do the above. I haven't been able to get anything that even comes close.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another XSLT example (this is more for @Kristian).

**XML Input** (input.xml)

```xml
<pdml version="0" creator="wireshark/3.2.2" time="Sun Mar 22 23:53:43 2020" capture_file="C:\Users\anyoung\AppData\Local\Temp\wireshark_Wi-Fi 2_20200322234518_a20824.pcapng">
    <packet>
        <proto name="geninfo" pos="0" showname="General information" size="66">
            <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="66"/>
            <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
            <field name="frame.cap_len" showname="Capture Length: 66 bytes (528 bits)" size="0" pos="0" show="66"/>
            <field name="frame.marked" showname="Frame is marked: False" size="0" pos="0" show="0"/>
            <field name="caplen" pos="0" show="66" showname="Captured Length" value="42" size="66"/>
            <field name="timestamp" pos="0" show="Mar 22, 2020 23:45:34.045301000 Pacific Daylight Time" showname="Captured Time" value="1584945934.045301000" size="66"/>
        </proto>
    </packet>
</pdml>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="tab" select="'&#x9;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="nl" select="'&#xA;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('field',$tab,'size',$tab,'value',$nl)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//field"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,$tab,@size,$tab,@value,$nl)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python 3**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")

new_tree = tree.xslt(xslt)

print(new_tree)
```

**Printed Output**

```
field   size    value
frame.cap_len   0   
frame.marked    0   
frame.cap_len   0   
frame.marked    0   
caplen  66  42
timestamp   66  1584945934.045301000
```

Answer (score 0):

## lxml

https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

lxml will allow you to transform XML documents using XSLT. For some reason, XSLT is overlooked and brute-force programming objects are used instead. Nevertheless, I prefer to use XLST when handling and transforming XML data.

I highly recommend learning XSLT and utilizing it regularly if you must handle XML data on a daily basis.

## XLST to transform your XML document: packet.xsl

Variables are used for delimiter and end-of-line (EOL) to allow for easy modification.

Templates for header-row and field are used to allow the re-arrangement or addition of new fields when necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" media-type="string" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="'&#x9;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EOL" select="'&#xA;'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/pdml/packet/proto">
        <xsl:call-template name="header-row"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="field"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@size"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$EOL"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="header-row">
        <xsl:element name="row">
            <xsl:text>field</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>size</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
            <xsl:text>value</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$EOL"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Example Python XML/XSLT transformation code

Use the python script provided by @Daniel Haley. I just named my file test.py

## Execute XSLT with XML input

- XSLT = packet.xsl
- XML = packet.xml

Assuming your packet.xml is a well formed XML document and not an incomplete fragement.

```
./test.py
```

Tab delimited output.

```
field   size    value
frame.cap_len   0   
frame.marked    0   
frame.cap_len   0   
frame.marked    0   
caplen  66  42
timestamp   66  1584945934.045301000
```

Comment: I agree that XSLT is a great option, but creating a bunch of elements with `xsl:element` is confusing when you're outputting text. http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfz

Comment: @DanielHaley, I only created XML elements to allow for the option of XML or plain text. This is merely an example that answered the question and to point him in the right direction. Many ways to skin the cat...

Comment: Unfortunately, lxml doesn't seem to produce output using your XSTL. I originally wanted to do exactly what you did; however, lxml etree.parse only seems to work when an XML document is produced. It would be great to see lxml properly utilize your XSLT.

Comment: Nice! Maybe I should post a question asking why my example won’t work with your XSLT 

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Haley, I took a snippet of code from a command-line tool that I wrote 2 years ago. The tool needed to be flexible enough to produce XML or plain text with or without an XLST document. I should have went with your 2 liner. Cheers